# How to automate a change in a populated cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Could you please help? I want to create a running total based on paid and unpaid work against the proposed cost. For instance, I have column A as quoted/proposed cost for works and B as final payment. Columns A and B could have different values, which could go up or down.

Two rows of my table would look like:

A1 = £3000   B1= 0

A2= £25000   B2= 15000

etc. My plan is to sum column A to give the total proposed costs. However, once these costs are paid, i.e. B2 is populated, I want A2 to go to zero so that it is removed from the total proposed costs.

I know I can do this easily by adding another column, but this is part of a larger document, so would like to reduce the amount of  columns. Is what I want even possible? I tried - IF(B1>0,A1="") and IF(B1>0,A1=0) in hope conditionally formatting would work, but obviously, it didn't. Putting a formula in column A would also not work as I need to populate it with unique figures. I can change column B to a drop down column stating PAID and UNPAID if that makes the system work.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want a sum of values in column A where their corresponding column-B value is zero.
This is easy enough using [SUMIF Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) as follows:

```
=SUMIF(B:B, 0, A:A)
```

NB the above refers to whole columns `B:B` and `A:A`, so you wouldn't be able to put this formula in either of those columns as it would give a circular reference error. Use limited-length ranges like `A1:A100` if you will be putting the total direectly above or below your data.